# Convertir una tabla con datos en filas a columnas en MSSQL Server

Tags: sql-server, subconsultas

tengo una tabla en MSSQLServer que tiene 50 millones de registros y necesito que la información de algunos campos que están en filas pasarlos a columnas, realice una consulta con sub consultas pero el tiempo de ejecución es interminable, funcionaba cuando la tabla era pequeña.
Envío una muestra de la tabla, el resultado esperado y la consulta que realice

Estructura de la tabla:

[image: La tabla tiene campos repetidos ya que fue diseñada de esa forma y tengo que adaptarme:]

Resultado esperado:
[image: El resultado que necesito obtener es los valores en forma horizontal (transpuesto) de la forma:]

La consulta que arme y funciona con una tabla con pocos datos es la siguiente.

--Primero creo una tabla temporal para poner los datos de forma horizontal (devuelve 5 filas)

```
with 
tmp_taData as (Select distinct a.id, a.form,a.orden, a.fecha,
(select b.valorcasilla from dbprico.dbo.taData b where a.orden=b.orden and casilla='101') casilla101,
(select b.valorcasilla from dbprico.dbo.taData b where a.orden=b.orden and casilla='102') casilla102,
(select b.valorcasilla from dbprico.dbo.taData b where a.orden=b.orden and casilla='103') casilla103,
(select b.valorcasilla from dbprico.dbo.taData b where a.orden=b.orden and casilla='104') casilla104,
(select b.valorcasilla from dbprico.dbo.taData b where a.orden=b.orden and casilla='105') casilla105,
(select b.valorcasilla from dbprico.dbo.taData b where a.orden=b.orden and casilla='106') casilla106,
(select b.valorcasilla from dbprico.dbo.taData b where a.orden=b.orden and casilla='107') casilla107
from dbprico.dbo.taData a
where a.form = '178')
--La consulta final para obtener los últimos datos ingresados (max) que podria ser por la fecha o el orden (devuelve 2 filas)
Select a.id,a.form, a.orden, a.fecha, a.casilla101, a.casilla102, a.casilla103, a.casilla104, a.casilla105, a.casilla106, a.casilla107
from tmp_taData a
where a.orden=(select max(b.orden) from tmp_taData b where a.id=b.id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás leyendo la tabla unas 16 veces y eso termina por ser lento. Lo que debes hacer es generar un agregado condicional para convertir filas en columnas. Estoy utilizando MAX() que es una buena opción cuando solo habrá un valor pero cualquier función de agregado puede funcionar dependiendo del caso.

```
SELECT id,
    form,
    orden,
    fecha,
    MAX( CASE WHEN casilla = 101 THEN valorcasilla END) AS casilla101,
    MAX( CASE WHEN casilla = 102 THEN valorcasilla END) AS casilla102,
    MAX( CASE WHEN casilla = 103 THEN valorcasilla END) AS casilla103,
    MAX( CASE WHEN casilla = 104 THEN valorcasilla END) AS casilla104,
    MAX( CASE WHEN casilla = 105 THEN valorcasilla END) AS casilla105,
    MAX( CASE WHEN casilla = 106 THEN valorcasilla END) AS casilla106,
    MAX( CASE WHEN casilla = 107 THEN valorcasilla END) AS casilla107
FROM dbo.taData a
WHERE a.form = '178'
GROUP BY id,
    form,
    orden,
    fecha;
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias Luis, desconocía esa forma de transformar filas en columnas, el problema fue solucionado.

Comment: Si la respuesta soluciona tu problema, se recomienda que la marques como aceptada para que la gente pueda identificarla como tal.

Comment: Ya esta gracias